# Is it possible execute a sql Insert sentence in an Android SQliteDatabase.query comand?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a simple sql database with two fields and I would like to insert some values in the database with the sql insert comand. Is it possible ?
The database is the following :
id valueA valueB
Thanks
Gorka

Comment: please explain whats your problem or give some code.just cant understand

Answer (score 0):

yes in some case its true, SQLLite omit some features of SQL but in insert they work

For Information [click hear](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html)